# How to limit two inputs with custom maxlength?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to limit two inputs with custom maxlength ?

I am setting a custom limit `$limit = "500";` and trying to limit user words in two inputs. I want to limit first input maxlength and count words in first input, than limit second input maxlength with words left from my custom limit.

I want to set length together max length 500, one can have max 100 and one can have max 400.
and if first  input has less words than 100, then add rest of the words left to the second input max length.
like : first input has 95 words in, 5 words left to reach limit.

then change second input maxlentgh to 405,

I create inputs like this :

```js
function maxLength(el) {
  if (!('maxLength' in el)) {
    var max = el.attributes.maxLength.value;
    el.onkeypress = function() {
      if (this.value.length >= max) return false;
    };
  }
}

maxLength(document.getElementById("title"));

function validateLength(el, word_left_field, len) {
  document.all[word_left_field].value = len - el.value.length;
  if (document.all[word_left_field].value < 1) {
    alert("You can add max " + len + " words .");
    el.value = el.value.substr(0, len);
    document.all[word_left_field].value = 0;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" maxlength="100" onChange="return validateLength(this, 'word_left', 100);" onKeyUp="return validateLength(this, 'word_left', 100);">
<input type="text" name="word_left" value="100" style="width: 25;" readonly="true" size="3">
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" maxlength="400" onChange="return validateLength(this, 'word_left', 400);" onKeyUp="return validateLength(this, 'word_left', 400);">
<input type="text" name="word_left" value="400" style="width: 25;" readonly="true" size="3">
```

so total of both inputs is 500.

I tried to set html 5 attributes *pattern=".{59,60}"* but they are same as setting attrbutes min and length.

But my javascript is limiting first input.
I tried several methods but didn't have a chance to make it work, would be to long question I didnt put all on here.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you well. You wan't to limit 2 input elements to have a max length of 500 together? So they can have 250 each, or one 100 and one 400, etc?

Comment: I want to do what you say, I want to set length together max length 500, one can have 100 and one can have 400. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I belive that you need something like this:

```js
var _maxLength = 500;
var _lengthInput = 0;

var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var p = document.getElementById("total");

p.innerHTML = _maxLength;

input1.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  this.maxLength = _maxLength + this.value.length;
  _lengthInput = this.value.length;
});

input1.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {

  if (_lengthInput == this.value.length)
    return;
  if (_lengthInput > this.value.length) {
    _maxLength += _lengthInput - this.value.length;
  } else {
    _maxLength -= this.value.length - _lengthInput;
  }

  total.innerHTML = _maxLength;
});

input2.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  this.maxLength = _maxLength + this.value.length;
  _lengthInput = this.value.length;
});

input2.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  if (_lengthInput == this.value.length)
    return;
  if (_lengthInput > this.value.length) {
    _maxLength += _lengthInput - this.value.length;
  } else {
    _maxLength -= this.value.length - _lengthInput;
  }

  total.innerHTML = _maxLength;
});
```

```html
Input 1 <input type="text" id="input1">
<br /> Input 2 <input type="text" id="input2">
<br />
<p>Characters remaining: <span id="total"></span> </p>
```

Comment: is it posible to add max lentgh to control maxlentgh of inputs with javascript ? well forget about this code allredy does it .lol

Comment: Yes, is possible! You can access the maxLength property of the input. For example: 
document.getElementById("idElement").maxLength = 40

Comment: When I change maxlentgh propety to `var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").maxLength = 60;` then it stops showing words left but looks like counting is working behind   @MarcusVinnicius

Answer (score -1):

I hope below code helps you,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#subject").on("keypress", function () {
   var titleLength = $("#title").val().length;
    var titleMaxLength = $("#title").attr("maxLength");
    var titleWordLeft = titleMaxLength - titleLength
    var subjectLength = $("#subject").data("charlength"); 
    var subjectMaxLength = titleWordLeft + subjectLength;
    $("#subject").attr("maxLength",subjectMaxLength);
    
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" maxlength="100">

<input type="text" name="word_left" value="100" style="width: 25;" readonly="true" size="3">

<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" data-charlength="400">


<input type="text" name="word_left" value="400" style="width: 25;" readonly="true" size="3">
```

Comment: I tried code but looks like it does nothing :(  do I have to use it with my javascript codes ?

Comment: @kuran You can remove ur code and just try posted the JQuery and html update code. You ll get to know the output When you Run the posted snippet

Comment: OP doesn't seem to use jQuery.